# Is there a way to get the git hash for a library installed by vcpkg

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019, vcpkg

My environment: Windows 10 64-bit, MSVC 2019 community edition

Currently I am using exiv2lib in one of my projects and I have installed the 'current' version of the 0.27.3 branch using vcpkg. This branch is also still under development, i. e. updates are committed to the branch every so often. I understand that I can update the vcpkg library as needed.

What I would like to get is the hash of the master repo on Github for the library version/commit my app is linked with, so that I can either check for the linked version against a specific version I made code 'adaptations' for, or at least be able to display the hash in the About dialog for later reference.

The library version is really not enough since it does not include any build number.
FWIW, I understand that there are some issues with/objections to a build number or its equivalent, because when using git, different repositories can/will have different build numbers or hashes.
However, I want to use/get the hash of the 'master' repo, which I believe would not be affected by this consideration.
Since this question concern both Git & vcpkg, I am posting here to hopefully get views and comments from both sides.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. A *repository* does not have a (as in one, single) hash ID. A repository is a collection of objects, each of which has a hash ID. No one particular repository is the master or central repository unless someone designates it as such, and two different people can disagree as to which repository is "more masterful". If you're looking for the Git hash ID of some particular commit, just have Git print out the hash ID of that particular commit: those really are universal, across every Git repository.

Comment: But I have decided to call the remote Exiv2 Github repo as "the master". This information is for my use, using my assumption. And I do want to use the  current; commit hash. 
My problem is how to get that from the vcpkg installation.

Comment: OK, so by "master repo" you really mean "exiv2 github repo" (that's appropriately specific). You now just need to designate which *commit* in that repo and/or figure out how to get vcpkg to spit out the commit hash (the latter might be impossible but if you can identify how vcpkg picks some commit, e.g., if it uses a particular tag name, you can have github resolve the name to the hash ID).

Comment: One of the things I find is that vcpkd downloads a file with a name such as
Exiv2-exiv2-194bb65ac568a5435874c9d9d73b1c8a68e4edec.tar.gz where I presume the hex string following the dash might be the  current SHA-1 hash , but I am as yet unsure of how I might be able to use it if I can confirm my assumption.

Comment: That does *look* like a commit hash, but I don't know anything about vcpkg. You could check to see whether, on whatever server it's getting this from, some tag name or branch name translates to that hash ID (e.g., run `git ls-remote` against that repository and look)—but that's just one sample; who knows what it does for all cases?

Comment: When I run that command against the Exiv2 code I have clones from Github, the output actually does contain a line with that hash. So I a a step closer. Thank you